# Rails Model Namespaces: Could not find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, namespaces

**This is not a duplicate of 'How do I explicitly specify a Model's table-name mapping in Rails?', as I am looking for a way to not explicitly set the table names. Instead I want to automatically set the table names accordingly to the inheritance of a model.**

I've got the following model structure:

```
models
  First (inheritance)
    Second (inheritance)
      Third (model)
  User (model)
    Second (model)
```

I have the following tables in the database:

```
first_second_thirds
users
user_seconds
```

When I execute the following code:

```
First::Second::Third.create(id: 1)
User.create(id: 1)
User::Second.create(id: 1)
```

I get that error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'thirds'

How do I tell the model the appropriate database table?

**EDIT:** Adding Code Examples

*db/migrate/20170305200503_create_first_second_third.rb*

```
class CreateFirstSecondThirds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :first_second_thirds do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*db/migrate/20161114164114_devise_create_users.rb*

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*db/migrate/20170305145804_create_user_stories.rb*

```
class CreateUserSeconds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_seconds do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*app/models/first/second/third.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

*app/models/user/second.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: are those all using inheritance or modules?  Actual code would probably be helpful.

Comment: @Anthony I added some details to the post. If you still need some sample code, I could add that as well.

Comment: Hiya - yes please show us some real code snippets - it's hard to debug a verbal description of code :)

Comment: @TarynEast Ok, I've added some sample code for better understading.

Comment: If you check out the error-message you got: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'thirds'` rails is expecting you to call the table by the class name itself, ie `thirds` - Rails won't automatically detect module-nested namespace (ie `First::Second::Third`). Note: the naming convention you have there is *not* inheritance, but module namepsaces. If you want to add the module-nesting as part of your database table, names, you'll need to use explicit table_names or use `table_name_prefix` in your modules.

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about `table_name_prefix`. :)